# How to read a json file in web2py using python code and return the dictionaries inside the json file?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def a():
    import json
    path=open('C:\\Users\\Bishal\\code\\57.json').read()
    config=json.load(path)
    for key in config:
        return key
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Your code needs to be indented 4 spaces to look like code.

Answer (score 0):

You have already read the file `path=open('C:\Users\Bishal\code\57.json').read()`, so when you try to load with `json.load(path)`, the file pointer is at the end of the file; hence nothing gets loaded or parsed.

Either load the file directly into `json`, or read the contents and then parse the string with `json.loads` (note the *`s`*)

Option 1:

```
path = open(r'C:\Users\Bishal\code\57.json').read()
config = json.loads(path)
```

Option 2:

```
path = open(r'C:\Users\Bishal\code\57.json')
config = json.load(path)
path.close()
```

Then you can do whatever you like with the result:

```
for key,item in config.items():
    print('{} - {}'.format(key, item))
```